# Error on website link

Tags: html

Server Error in '/Pictures' Application.

**Source Error:**

> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

**Stack Trace:**

```
    [ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index and count must refer to a location within the string.Parameter name: count]
   System.String.Remove(Int32 startIndex, Int32 count) +0
   _Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +114
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +99
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +50
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +627
```

Comment: Do you have some code that the error is referencing.

Comment: Its a fairly big piece of code and not entirely sure exactly where the error is.  Any idea where on the code the error is?  Obviously its a String. Just don't understand the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you're calling this method while passing integer values for the starting index and amount of the String to remove that are invalid for the string. For example, if your string is 5 characters long, `startIndex` must be between 0 and 4 and count is basically `4-startIndex`. You can't remove 7 characters from a 4 character string. You also can't have the starting index as 8 if the string is only 4 characters long.

That's what `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` is. The arguments you're passing to a method as parameters are out of the range acceptable to apply to the String.

This is why me asking for code earlier was important, because we could likely find what part of your code was creating or passing incorrect values to the method.